# If two variable values are identical then it is said to be sharing same memory

Tags: python, python-2.7

If two variable values are identical then it is said to be sharing same memory...
so python follows shared memory concept ?....and if i change one value will it change another?

Comment: No... variables with the same values do not share the same memory. (some exceptions for small values).

Answer (score 2):

See Python data model described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

> Types affect almost all aspects of object behavior. Even the importance of object identity is affected in some sense: for immutable types, operations that compute new values may actually return a reference to any existing object with the same type and value, while for mutable objects this is not allowed. E.g., after a = 1; b = 1, a and b may or may not refer to the same object with the value one, depending on the implementation, but after c = []; d = [], c and d are guaranteed to refer to two different, unique, newly created empty lists. (Note that c = d = [] assigns the same object to both c and d.)